# All combinations of matrix parenthesizations

Tags: dynamic-programming

I have this problem:

Let $S$ be a set which is the domain with two operators $+$ and $*$ 
and an element $0$ such that:

$+$ is a binary operator that is:

- associative
- commutative
- idempotent (that is, $x + x = x$ for all $x \in S$)
- $x + 0 = 0 + x = x$ for all $x \in S$

$*$ is a binary operator that is:

- non-associative
- non-commutative
- $x * 0 = 0 * x = 0$ for all $x \in S$

The operators $+$ and $*$ satisfy the distributive laws:
That is,for all $x,y,z \in S$,

- $ x * (y + z) = x*y + x*z$
- $ (y + z) * x = y*x + z*x$

Given $n$ elements $x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n$ from $S$ describe an 
algorithm to compute the sum of products of $x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n$ in this
order, under all possible groupings for the products.

For example, if $n = 3$, it is required to compute
$
(x_1 * (x_2 * x_3)) + ((x_1 * x_2) * x_3)
$

---

It looks similar to Matrix Chain Multiplication at first, but since it's using all groupings, not just an optimal one, I figured that wouldn't work here.  My next thought was that there would only be $n^3$ ways to multiply $n$ numbers together, but that doesn't account for groupings like $(x_1*x_2)(x_3*x_4)$.  I'm pretty lost on this now though, can someone point me in the right direction?